# Sequences in open intervals

Tags: real-analysis

I have the following statement and my attempt at trying to prove it. Is my proof ok? Comments/suggestions are welcome.

> Let $c$ be a real number contained in the open interval $(a,b)$, prove
>   that there exists two sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ both contained in
>    $(a,b)$ such that $x_n < c < y_n$ for all $n \in \mathbf{N}$ and $\lim x_n = \lim y_n = c$.

My attempt: We know that $c$ is a limit point of the open interval $(a,b)$, hence, there exists a convergent sequence $(a_n)$ contained in $(a,b)$ where $c = \lim a_n$ and $a_n \neq c$ for all $n \in \mathbf{N}$. The terms of the sequence $(a_n)$ are either greater than or less than $c$. Denote the subsequence of $(a_n)$ that contains all the terms less than $c$ as $(x_n)$ and the subsequence of $(a_n)$ that contains all the terms greater than $c$ as $(y_n)$. Thus, $x_n < c < y_n$ for all $n \in \mathbf{N}$. Since $a_n \neq c$ this implies that $\lim x_n = \lim y_n = c$ because $x_n$ and $y_n$ are subsequences of $(a_n)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not quite a valid proof because you don't know if there will be infinitely many elements of your sequence greater than $c$ (or smaller than $c$). Though the idea is good. The issue is that it is not very constructive since you don't know anything about your sequence $(a_n)$.

Let me propose you an alternative.

Consider for all $n$:

$$\begin{cases} x_n:=c-\frac {a+c}{n} \\  y_n:=c+\frac {a+c}{n}.\end{cases}$$

You can verify that $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ satisfies all your conditions.